# I am getting this error even after declaring scalar variable"'Must declare the scalar variable "@col_shipping_price"

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I am trying to fetch data from the source and save into the Database but I am facing this issue even after declaring the scalar variable. find below the approach which I tried. The issue I am facing:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@col_shipping_price".'

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AmazonEnvelope));
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\*********\Desktop\16315550943018039.xml");
        object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        AmazonEnvelope XmlData = (AmazonEnvelope)obj;
        reader.Close();
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ABDUL-TPS\TPSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=Zoho_Amz_API;User ID=zohoapiservice;Password=**********");
        cnn.Open();
        for (int i = 0; i < XmlData.Message.Count; i++)
        {
            string sqlquery = "if not exists (select * from tbl_AMZ_API_sample where col_sku like '" + XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.SKU + "') insert into tbl_AMZ_API_sample(col_amazon_order_id, col_merchant_order_id, col_purchase_date, col_last_updated_date, col_order_status, col_fulfillment_channel, col_sales_channel, col_order_channel, col_url, col_ship_service_level, col_product_name, col_sku, col_asin, col_number_of_items, col_item_status, col_quantity, col_currency, col_item_price, col_item_tax, col_shipping_price, col_shipping_tax, col_gift_wrap_price, col_gift_wrap_tax, col_item_promotion_discount, col_ship_promotion_discount, col_ship_city, col_ship_state, col_ship_postal_code, col_ship_country, col_promotion_ids, col_is_business_order, col_purchase_order_number, col_price_designation, col_fulfilled_by, col_last_update_time) values(@col_amazon_order_id, @col_merchant_order_id, @col_purchase_date, @col_last_updated_date, @col_order_status, @col_fulfillment_channel, @col_sales_channel, @col_order_channel, @col_url, @col_ship_service_level, @col_product_name, @col_sku, @col_asin, @col_number_of_items, @col_item_status, @col_quantity, @col_currency, @col_item_price, @col_item_tax, @col_shipping_price, @col_shipping_tax, @col_gift_wrap_price, @col_gift_wrap_tax, @col_item_promotion_discount, @col_ship_promotion_discount, @col_ship_city, @col_ship_state, @col_ship_postal_code, @col_ship_country, @col_promotion_ids, @col_is_business_order, @col_purchase_order_number, @col_price_designation, @col_fulfilled_by, @col_last_update_time)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, cnn);

            for (int j = 0; j < XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.ItemPrice.Component.Count; j++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_amazon_order_id", XmlData.Message[i].Order.AmazonOrderID);

                if (XmlData.Message[i].Order.MerchantOrderID == null)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_merchant_order_id", DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_merchant_order_id", XmlData.Message[i].Order.MerchantOrderID);
                }
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_purchase_date", XmlData.Message[i].Order.PurchaseDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_last_updated_date", Global.unique.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_order_status", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderStatus);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_fulfillment_channel", XmlData.Message[i].Order.FulfillmentData.FulfillmentChannel);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_sales_channel", XmlData.Message[i].Order.SalesChannel);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_ship_service_level", XmlData.Message[i].Order.FulfillmentData.ShipServiceLevel);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_product_name", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.ProductName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_sku", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.SKU);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_asin", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.ASIN);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_number_of_items", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.NumberOfItems);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_item_status", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.ItemStatus);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_quantity", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.Quantity);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_currency", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.ItemPrice.Component[j].Amount.Currency);
                switch (XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.ItemPrice.Component[j].Type)
                {
                    case "Principal":
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_item_price", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.ItemPrice.Component[j].Amount.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_item_tax", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.ItemPrice.Component[j].Amount.Text);
                        break;
                    case "Shipping":
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_shipping_price", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.ItemPrice.Component[j].Amount.Text);
                        break;
                    case "GiftWrap":
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_gift_wrap_price", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.ItemPrice.Component[j].Amount.Text);
                        break;
                    case "Shipping-Tax":
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_shipping_tax", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.ItemPrice.Component[j].Amount.Text);
                        break;
                    default:
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_gift_wrap_tax", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.ItemPrice.Component[j].Amount.Text);
                        break;
                }
                if (XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.Promotion == null)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_item_promotion_discount", 0);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_ship_promotion_discount", 0);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_promotion_ids", 0);
                }

                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_item_promotion_discount", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.Promotion.ItemPromotionDiscount);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_ship_promotion_discount", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.Promotion.ShipPromotionDiscount);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_promotion_ids", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.Promotion.PromotionIDs);
                }

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_ship_city", XmlData.Message[i].Order.FulfillmentData.Address.City);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_ship_state", XmlData.Message[i].Order.FulfillmentData.Address.State);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_ship_postal_code", XmlData.Message[i].Order.FulfillmentData.Address.PostalCode);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_ship_country", XmlData.Message[i].Order.FulfillmentData.Address.Country);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_is_business_order", XmlData.Message[i].Order.IsBusinessOrder);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_purchase_order_number", XmlData.Message[i].Order.PurchaseOrderNumber);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_price_designation", XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.PriceDesignation);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_fulfilled_by", XmlData.Message[i].Order.FulfilledBy);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_Order_Channel", DBNull.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_url", DBNull.Value);
                Console.WriteLine(XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.ItemPrice.Component[j].Type);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Someone help please.

Comment: Why are to injecting the value of `XmlData.Message` when you clearly know about parameters (although I also suggest using `Parameters.Add` not `Parameters.AddWithValue`)

Comment: The declaration of `@col_shipping_price` is in a `Switch` but it's always in your SQL Statement.

Answer (score 2):

You obviously know in general how to use parameterized queries, so why don't you use it in the `SELECT` part of the query here:

> ```
> ... like '" + XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.SKU + "' ...
> ```

You should also use parameters there. And the `LIKE` could be changed to an `=` unless `XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.SKU` includes wildcards, which seems unlikely.

On your problem:

You have `@col_shipping_price` in the `INSERT` part of your query apparently meant as a parameter. Yet you only set this parameter if `XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.ItemPrice.Component[j].Type` is `Shipping` in the `switch()`. That is, in all other cases `@col_shipping_price` stays as it is in the query and isn't replaced. SQL Server thinks it is a variable and rightfully complains that it wasn't declared. The same problem might occur with some of you other parameters it seems.

You have some options here.

1. Replace all the parameters all the time. Probably use `DBNull` if you have no actual value. Unless there are not null constraints on the columns that should work. If you do it like that there's also no need to rebuild the query in every iteration. Create it once, optionally `Prepare()` it and then just change the parameters' values in the iteration. Performance may benefit from that.
2. Build different queries depending on `XmlData.Message[i].Order.OrderItem.ItemPrice.Component[j].Type`. That way you can simply leave placeholders of unused parameters out.

And you should be careful when using `AddWithValue()`, even avoid using it completely. It needs to guess the data type of the columns on the database, sometimes miserably fails and produces funny errors. Better use the `Add()` overloads with explicit type arguments. Something to read on this topic: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)